# PostGre - Campo Id (Integer) de uma tabela pode ir de 1 até quanto?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no PostGre cujo campo Id é do tipo Integer e chave primária.
A medida que registros vão sendo salvos, a numeração vai de 1 até quanto?

Sou acostumado com o banco de dados Dataflex, onde os registros das tabelas (por padrão) começam de 1 e vão até 999999.

Há alguma diferença entre PostGre e SQL Server nesses aspectos?
Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a Tabela **Numeric Types** da [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) do Postgres 9.1, **integer** é 4 bytes que vai de **-2147483648 à +2147483647**

[image: Tabela]

Comment: Obrigado @Fabricio!